# How to delete multiple namespaces with label option

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl

I have generated a bunch of namespaces like below and now i want to delete only these name spaces without deleting kube-system namespaces,i tried with grep but no success

> kubectl delete namespaces | grep "gatling*"
>   error: resource(s) were provided, but no name, label selector, or --all flag specified

[Multiple namespaces](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UNL86.png)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

First get the names of the namespaces you want to delete:

```
kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep gatling
```

With `-o custom-columns=:metadata.name` we output only the names of the services. The output is piped to `grep`, which filters them by looking for `gatling`.

Then run the delete command for each line with `xargs`:

```
kubectl get namespaces --no-headers=true -o custom-columns=:metadata.name | grep gatling | xargs kubectl delete namespace
```

Comment: awesome,worked like charm,one more request could you also please describe in brief what those commands are doing

Comment: Added some more explanation. Which part you don't understand?